# Reference a different part of the document and have it automatically update?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

In my open office document I occasionally have little notes saying something like `(see p31)`. Is there some way I could insert some kind of anchor for these so that they automatically update if I add or remove a few pages somewhere. It's getting on my nerves having to go and update them all manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way you can do it:

- Go to the page you wish to refer to by number.
- Go to **Insert->Cross Reference...**.
- Choose **Set Reference** in the left-hand pane
- Enter a name and click **OK**.
- Go to the page where you want to insert the page number.
- Go to **Insert->Cross Reference...** again
- Ensure **Insert Reference** is selected in the left-hand pane and choose the reference you added earlier.
- In the *Insert reference to* section ensure **Page** is selected.
- Click **OK**.

There are also options to reference existing parts of the document, e.g. headers. There is some documentation available for this: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_automatic_cross-references

Note that the fields sometimes take a while to update automatically. If you press F9 then if forces them to be refreshed.